# Grab all the posts for particular category

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

So I have a class called Recipe and inside I have a `get()` method as shown below:

```
public function get()
{
    $taxonomies = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'recipe-categories',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ]);

    $output = '';

    if (!empty($taxonomies)):

        $output = '<div>';
        foreach ($taxonomies as $category)
        {
            if ($category->parent == 0)
            {
                $output .= '<p><a href="' . get_home_url() . '/recipe-categories/' . esc_attr__($category->slug) . '">'. esc_attr__($category->name) .'</a></p>';
                foreach ($taxonomies as $subcategory) {
                    if ($subcategory->parent == $category->term_id) {
                        $output.= '<p>'. esc_attr($subcategory->term_id) . ' ' . esc_html($subcategory->name) .'</p>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $output .= '<div>';
    endif;

    return $output;
}
```

This gives me all the categories in my custom post type:
[image]

If I click into one of the specific categories, it will lead me to a template that I'm using that will display the category posts:

`'/recipe-categories/' . esc_attr__($category->slug)`

Here is the code that I'm using inside the template:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
    <div class="four-sixths first">
        <?php

        $args = [
            'category' => 'bread',
            'post_type' =>  'recipe'
        ];
        $postslist = get_posts($args);

        foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

I've added the `'category' => 'bread'` slug for testing purposes and I'm getting all the posts particular to the bread category.

The real question is, how can I make it detect my category slug and pull in all posts that are linked to a particular category?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the standard category templates and URLs? you could easily add a `category-bread.php` to your theme then visit `yoursite.com/recipe-categories/bread`, the `get_posts` would be completely unnecessary, and you wouldn't run into the pagination problem your current template has. Also, `esc_attr__` is a translation API, you shouldn't pass random variables into it, only strings. It also takes 2 parameters, not 1, so it'll be generating PHP warnings/notices behind the scenes

Comment: you might actually find it easier to register a custom taxonomy named `recipe-categories`, giving you `taxonomy-recipe-categories.php`, and letting you avoid renaming the category URLs, or having to add a custom template for all your categories individually, or having to build page templates for everything then manually create pages

Comment: @TomJNowell, the only reason that I'm going this route is because it's all inside a mu-plugins directory - I'm not touching any frameworks or child themes at all.

I have a registered custom taxonomy called recipe-categories.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting anything other than basic single file snippets in the `mu-plugins` folder, there's no need for frameworks either. If you need to load entire plugins you can just include them from the `mu-plugins` file, you don't have to transplant them into that folder, and you shouldn't be building themes inside there either. Having templates in the `mu-plugins` folder is extremely unusual and exotic, and can significantly change the meaning of the problem, you should edit your Q to mention this